# Using an Ethernet cable and USB Ethernet adapter at the same time?

Tags: ip, ethernet, network, layer1, lan

What would happen on using an Ethernet cable connected to one network and 
then plugging in another Ethernet cable but using an USB Ethernet adapter from a
different network.
Would it connect to both or what ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you plug the "Ethernet cable" into an onboard NIC, the USB adapter just represents another NIC with another network connection. This makes the host *multi-homed*, connected to both networks.

Note that the host most likely gets a second default gateway. Which default gateway is actually used depends on the interface metrics configured manually, by the OS or by DHCP. Note however that host configurations are off-topic here.